# How to know if a Java SE class or method is thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

For example:

```
static private DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
public static void format(final Date date) { 
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             System.out.println(df.format(date));
         } 
     });
}
```

The `DateFormat` class is documented as not a synchronized class, but if we use just the format method, it can't change the status of the whole class?

Suppose it's declared private, how can one be sure that the code is thread safe?

What is the best way to fix this code?:

1. Using a different instance for every thread.
2. Using a synchronized block.

Comment: By reading the documentation carefully, both the class documentation and the specific method documentation.

Comment: DateFormat especially mentions it's not thread safe if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ok it is documented as not synchornized Class, if we use just the format Method, it can't change the statut of the hole Class?

Comment: It is specifically documented as *not synchronized".

Comment: The hole class is documented not safe but how to know if a specifique method chage the state of the Class or not ?

Comment: If a class is documented as non threadsafe, like DateFormat is, you stop speculating about which method might or might not actually be thread-safe. You just don't share the instance between several threads. BTW, the fact that format() changes or doesn't change the state is irrelevant: if another method is called concurrently, and that method changes the state, then format() will have its invariants broken, and could return a wrong result, or throw an exception, or anything else.

Comment: but if am sure that this instance is private, and it can't be used anyware else, it could be useful to know if the method dosn't change his state?

Comment: It can be useful to read the source of a method and see how it is working, and the source is freely available on the Internet. However, you *cannot* rely on the implementation to stay the same through versions. And if your program doesn't allow any other threads to touch an object, why are you concerned about thread safety?

Comment: You could always write load test and see if data integrity is preserverd for your specific scenario.

Comment: i add a For iteration to the question

Comment: BTW, format() does change the state of the formatter. It uses a Calendar instance variable and mutates it each time format() is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- For a standard Java SE class, the best way to know whether or not the class is thread-safe is to carefully read its documentation. Always read both the class documentation and the method documentation. If either say it's not synchronized or not thread-safe, you know it's not thread-safe.
- Therefore, the `DateFormat` class is *not* thread safe. The documentation specifically says:

  > Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.
- Declaring a field `private` does *not* make your implementation thread-safe. `private` merely says that outside classes can't see that field. Let's look at your method:

  ```
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++) 
       new Thread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
               System.out.println(df.format(date));
           } 
       });
  ```

  The `Runnable` objects that you create are anonymous classes. Anonymous classes are *inner* classes, which have access to private fields of their surrounding class. If it wasn't so, your program would not compile - they could not access the `df` field.

  But they can. So in fact you are having 10 threads that are all accessing your one `DateFormat` object, referred to by `df`. Since we already know that `DateFormat` is *not* thread-safe, your program is not thread-safe.
- Furthermore, if two external threads have references to your object (I mean the object that has the `df` inside it. You didn't give the class declaration so I don't know what its name is). They have references to the same instance of your class. If both of them call `format` at the same time, both will be running `DateFormat.format` using the same private `df`. Thus, this is not going to be thread-safe.
- To be thread-safe, you need to synchronize on the object or use some other kind of lock (one lock for all the possible threads that access it), which is exactly what the documentation said to do.
- Another way is to have a completely local object, which is visible to only one thread. Not a field - a local variable, which has access to a uniquely created instance of `DateFormat` (so you have a new copy every time you call the method). Beware of anonymous classes, though! In your example, even if `df` was a local field to the `format` method, it would still not be thread-safe because all your threads would be accessing the same copy.

Comment: So even if the instance is local to the my method Format, and i am sure that all threads use only the Format method, which i suppose it is stateless, it still not thread safe?

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK You can't *suppose*. This is still not thread safe. If the documentation says it's not, then it's not. More than one thread accessing the instance = not thread safe.

Comment: Yes but they dont specify about every method, they document the hole class as not synchorinized, but i am pretty sure that format date should be stateless

Comment: it would be thread safe if you knew it was stateless. Until DateFormat.format implementation is changed, that is.

Comment: Again, you can't *suppose* or *assume* anything, @NassimMOUALEK. Since the class documentation says the class is not synchronized, it means any method is subject to implementation changes and can be implemented differently by different Java environment, and all those implementations *may* change state variables, hence, it's **not** thread-safe.

Comment: the best way to fix this code is to use a different instance for every Thread, or we should use a synchronized block ? which is better? probably the first solution i think

Comment: In this particular case I'd personally go with a synchronized block, as `System.out.println` is going to be slower anyway, and involves synchronization as well, so the delay for synchronization is going to be negligible. Besides, there is also a price for making copies, which is usually justifiable only if the thread uses the instance many times.

Comment: You mean System.out.println has its own synchronisation block, or we must use a synchronisation block for every System.out.println ?

Comment: I mean it has its own synchronization block.

Answer (score 3):

As per the docs, it is stated that the format is not thread safe.

**Synchronization**

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

[Date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

How to read this ? If you don't have explicit guarantee that some method is thread safe(or its documented as unsafe) then you cannot make any assumptions about it being safe.

However, if you really wish to only use single method which might not be statefull, you can always create high concurrency environment and test for data integrity with and without synchronization.

I have had similar question to this, with Ciphers and RSA.
The answer there shows one way how to test specific method of java SE class in general for this. Note however that implementation could change at any point, and by making your own implementation against implementation details rather then interface might cause some unpredictable issues in the future.

[testing for data integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997666/thread-safety-with-rsa-cipher/32005758#32005758)

Answer (score 2):

I know it is hard to believe, but DateFormat.format() actually modifies the DateFormat's state. For instance, for SimpleDateFormat:

```
// Called from Format after creating a FieldDelegate
private StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                            FieldDelegate delegate) {
    // Convert input date to time field list
    calendar.setTime(date);
```

where `calendar` is a field of DateFormat.

Therefore, I can only recommend you trust the documentation. It may know things you don't.