# How to get current logged in user in hibernate event listener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

I am using hibernate event listeners to record last modified time. I use a Custom Integrator to register the event listeners. I register my integrator by creating a file with a specific name in META-INF as explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#services-IntegratorService). I also want to record the username of the currently logged in user. I assume that information would be present in the HttpSession. But in the [MergeEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/MergeEventListener.html) I do not have access to the HttpSession. How do I get the HttpSession or is there any other way to get the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution I have seen is to use a servlet-filter to put the information into a `ThreadLocal` when the request comes in, so that you can access it from a static context at whatever arbitrary point down the stack that you need it.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned I am using spring.

Comment: Don't know that that would make a difference?

Comment: I can create a servlet filter and I have access to the User object in the session. How I do pass it to the eventlistener. Moreover this concern bothers me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/373613/161628

Comment: Ok may be I can remove the thread local in the destroy method.

Comment: Following your answer the way I am doing it is:
Create a public static threadLocal in servlet filter. populate it with the user object. Access the public static variable in the EntitySaveListener. Add it to the database table to log who updated the record. It seems to work. Can you give some more details on caveats or problems in using this approach? I definitely see the password in the thread. I am also going to use threadLocal.set(null) in my servlet filter. Any other things that I should be careful about?

Comment: You will probably need to add in some handling for a "system" user if you have any like, background jobs, JMS threads, similar things that may make DB updates outside the context of a web request.  I would also add a layer of abstraction between the class used to access user details from inside persistence code and the web-tier bound servlet filter, but that is to some extent academic.

Comment: Yeah I will need another layer of abstraction. I do not have any special users but there are some operations that update fields across multiple tables. There are some fields that are hidden from the user and are used internally. So updates to those fields should not shown in the modified timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one utility method in a singleton class and put the following line of code, which any time return the logged in Usrename

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

I did the same in my web applicaiton using Spring + Hibernate.

Hope this will help for you as well.